# Get running application flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background-process

I want to know the package of of the application currently running in phone in my flutter app, like the "Forest" application that when you open some applications an error pops up or a function is called.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

go to below link and read it, then u will understand flutter backgrounds how works.

[Background with Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

Edited:

code blow is what u want in android, now just search and find what library or method do it in Flutter.

```
ActivityManager activitymanager = 
(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

 RAP = activitymanager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo: RAP ){

Log.e("TAG",processInfo.processName);


 }
```

this print List of background apps in Logcat.

hope that be helpfully for you.

Comment: The data provided by the article is good but its not what I want. I still need to know what application is running

Comment: check the Edit.

Comment: Thanks, can I use it directly via platform channels?

Comment: in android yes, in flutter don’t know .Your Welcome
check answer if it helps you.

Comment: Hi amff ,Have you found any information about this feature ?